# Can I init an NSArray in a Singleton with specific values (like a const)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a Singleton and I'd like to declare an NSArray, but I'd like to init it with 5 (non -consecutive) integers.

Right now it's declared in the .h>Interface, .h>@property, and .m>@synthesize.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your singleton's -init method, simply create and initialize it there:

```
- (id)init
{
    _array = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:50], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3.72], [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:96], nil] retain];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Oops, integer, not string... Try `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` etc.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the info - I guess I'd better put more time into learning Obj-C...

Comment: @user1118321 Um, that's not working. Here's what I have: .h> `@interface GlobalData : NSObject {NSInteger *myArray;} @property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger *myArray;` .m> `@synthesize myArray;` .m>init> `mySingleton.myArray={3,10,16,24,30};`

Comment: @wayneh What you say, "that's not working," what happens with it? Compile error? Runtime error? I'd be curious to know so I don't make bad recommendations in the future. I'm glad your way is working, though.

Comment: @user1118321 Sorry, I might have confused you. Your sample is OK, but I'm trying to implement something more basic (if possible). My code doesn't work as the assignment in .m>init fails since the array has no bounds. I'd really prefer a "int" array so I don't have to mees with the NSNumber/object conversion. Still confusing?

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of items your putting into the array, or will the size of the array change over time? If it's fixed, you can declare it in your .h file as `NSInteger myArray[kMaxNumItems];`. If it's not fixed, then you need to allocate it in your -init method, and resize it if you want to add to it later. In that case, you'd declare it like you suggest: `NSInteger *myArray;` and then in your `-init` method, allocate it, like this: `myArray = malloc(sizeof(NSInteger)*5);` Later, if you want to add to it, you can do `myArray=realloc(myArray, sizeof(NSInteger)*num);`

Comment: I had not set up the array properly in the init method - all is well now. Thanks for the help, this worked.